# How to invoke the auto-complete window of PhraseExpress?

Tags: autocomplete, phraseexpress

I downloaded the portable version of the text auto-complete tool [PhraseExpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com/) and added some phrases to the `local phrase file`. What do I need to do to invoke the auto-complete text window of it? I tried my phrases in an OpenOffice text document, text-editor and Firefox and it never shows up. 
I'm using PhraseExpress v.11 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean with "Invoke the auto complete text window"? I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to configure it in any special way. Just start typing and PhraseExpress does the rest. See http://www.phraseexpress.com/autocomplete.htm for more information.

Check out the video below where the creators of PhraseExpress shows how to use and configure PhraseExpress for text autocompletion.

[[image: Video thumbnail]

Autocomplete text using PhraseExpress on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsDUtAIX54s)